# Find records with column containing specific values

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

I think my question really boils down do doing a sql `IN` on multiple values.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fa3ee/2) of what I have so far.

So long story short, I have `Cases` that have multiple `Types`.

I need to filter `Cases` containing certain `Types`

Say I have 6 rows (col1,col2)... (1,2),(1,3)(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)
How do I select only `Cases` that have 2, AND 3 AND 4 in col2?

2,3,4 is just a use case. It could be just about any combination (the SQL Fiddle has a couple tables that determine this).

Comment: Do you have a long term ceiling on the number of case types?

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow what you're asking, but no. Case Types can be added by users. And on top of that the users are able to choose any combination of types to determine what cases are "billable". Seriously been scratching my head on this all day.

Comment: I was thinking, if you had a low number of case types (e.g. 32), you might've been able to get away with some binary maths in the where clause. Doesn't sound like an option though.

Comment: Ah, yea I can't guarantee the number of Types.

Comment: Edited my answer (and now thinking maybe I should've just added a new one)

Answer (score 0):

is this a bit closer?

```
SELECT * from CaseTypes CT
INNER JOIN TypeBillable TB    ON CT.TypeId = TB.TypeId
where CT.CaseId in
(
select CaseID from CaseTypes
PIVOT (count (TypeId) for TypeId in ([2],[3],[4])) as x
where [2] > 0 and [3] > 0 and [4] > 0
)
```

Comment: That's a negative red rider. That returns cases matching "Any" I need an "All"...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select [CaseId]
from CaseTypes
where [TypeID] in (2,3,4)
group by [CaseId]
having count(distinct [TypeID]) = 3
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fa3ee/7))

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you might try:

Using Derived Tables:

```
SELECT a.col1
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM Cases WHERE col2 = 2) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT col1 FROM Cases WHERE col2 = 3) b ON a.col1 = b.col1
INNER JOIN (SELECT col1 FROM Cases WHERE col2 = 4) c ON a.col1 = c.col1
```

Using Aggregation:

```
SELECT col1
FROM Cases
GROUP BY col1
HAVING 
   SUM(CASE col2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
   SUM(CASE col2 WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
   SUM(CASE col2 WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because the `COUNT` of types I'm looking for isn't always 3. It could be 2, or 4 or etc different types.

Comment: @JIsaak -- How is it that you know which / how many types you're looking for.  Is this something you can anticipate?  For example, is there a characteristic (like 'billable', or 'even numbers only', etc.) that users are selecting through an interface?

Comment: The end users have an interface to set a `Type` as billable. They basically create the two "billable" tables in my SQL fiddle. For example they can choose: "Type 2 is billable 'only if' Type 3 AND Type 4 are also present" to the `Case`.